# Is there a difference between Chassidei and Tzadikei Umot HaOlam in goyim?

Tags: gentiles, rambam, noachide-laws, islam, noahidism

I have seen the Rambam Zt"l explain in Mishneh Torah Melakhim uMilchamot 8:11 that in order for one who is not Jewish to be considered as "Pious" (Chassidim) they have to abide by the Seven laws of Noah A"S, and the 13 Ikkarim. But I have also heard many other rabbis claim that people such as Muslims or other purely monotheistic Abrahamic faiths that follow the Seven laws of Noah A"S are considered to be "Righteous" (Tzadikim).